# Firebase how to detect if cached data is available

Tags: android, caching, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application that pulls some simple data from Firebase Realtime Database, and to make things simple here is the flow that I want to have.

**If phone is connected to the internet:**

- Get the data from the firebase database

**If phone is offline**

- If there is data in firebase cache -> get data from cache

  - If there is nothing in firebase cache -> show some default data stored locally in app

The problem is that I don't see possible way to detect if data is available in firebase cache. So when phone is offline I cannot see if I should display the locally stored data or cache from firebase database.

Comment: Firebase does it for you without adding any code.

Comment: I believe @ibrcic is asking how app can detect, if phone is offline, that the data being queried isn't cached (and show other default data in that case)

Comment: If you want a local cache that you can query for existence of data, you'll have to implement that yourself on top of the Firebase SDKs.

Comment: There is a way to determine if you are connected to firebase server, but not a way to determine what is the source of the data (if the cache or the remote server).

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you find a way to see if there is any data in the cache if a user is offline?

Comment: Did you get any proper answer?

Comment: No, sorry, seems that there is no way to do it as Firebase is not intended to work that way.

Answer (score 4):

Agree above answer, Firebase will do it for you, if you do it in the right way. In order to solve your problem, you should understand the difference between the two approaches of firebase offline cache  - reading-from-memory and reading-from-disk.

Read this article -> https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb

in your case, just add, `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` to enable reading from disk

and add `yourReferenceForFirebase.keepSynced(true);` to keep the data synched

then your app will work as you expected.

But, only this part: "If there is nothing in firebase cache -> show some default data stored locally in app", seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does it for you.

Firebase applications work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection.

Also firebase apps automatically handle temporary network interruptions.
Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes when network connectivity is restored.

If it is not enough and you need to work offline you can also enable the disk persistence just adding:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

EDIT:
There is no way to know whether a value comes from the local cache or from the remote server.

There is only a way to know if your app is currently connected to the Firebase Database server.
To achieve it you can [detect the connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) by listening for the `.info/connected` value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but unfortunately that is not exactly what I am looking for. I know that firebase handles all of those things automatically and I have set it up to do so without a problem. What I don't know is how to detect IF there is an actual cached data. For example if user is running the app for the first time and doesn't have internet connection. In this instance I want to show some default data and not data from the Firebase (because Firebase callback is never triggered). Also if user clears cached data from app etc.

Comment: @ibrcic I understand but you are using firebase in a wrong way in my opinion. It is a realtime database, it isn't sqllite database and you should follow the firebase approach. it is not important if the data showed is from the cache or from the server, you show in any case the data from firebase and if the first time you want to show something different you can do it, simply not showing the firebase data. You are looking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: To put it simply, data on firebase is the most recent one and default data in app is the one I put there when programming the app. I want to make sure to show the default data only when there is no internet connection AND there is no cached data. I think this is something that you should be able to do, check if there is an actual cached data so that I can display something if there is not.

Comment: @ibrcic I did some researches and I didn't find what you need. However there is a boolean that can tell you if you are connected to the firebase server or not. I've just edited the answer with this additional info.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I am wondering if this is still the status quo, or if there is a way now to determine if data is served from cache or from DB?